# How to Moq abstract class with default constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I would like to Moq an abstract class that has default parameters in it's constructor.  This is so that I can test the defaults are set, as well as testnig specific values. e.g. (note, this is purely an example class)

```
public abstract class AbstractClassToTest
  {
      private string _name;
      private int _someInt;
      private int _anotherInt;

      public AbstractClassToTest(string name, int someInt = 10, int anotherInt = 20)
      {
          _name = name;
          _someInt = someInt;
          _anotherInt = anotherInt;
      }
  }
```

and setup the Moq object as follows:

```
var act = new Mock<AbstractClassToTest>(MockBehavior.Loose, "namestring");
```

but this throws an error...

```
Message "Can not instantiate proxy of class:
Test.AbstractClassToTest.
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
System.String
Parameter name: constructorArguments"
```

How can I create moq the object and keep it's defaults?

Moq: v 4.0.10827.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Moq won't mock class types, only interfaces. Probably because even an abstract class may have a lot of "concrete" implementations in it, and a lot of state.</s>

Instead, make your own mocked class:

```
class AbstractClassToTestMOCK : AbstractClassToTest
{
  internal AbstractClassToTestMOCK(string name, int someInt = 10, int anotherInt = 20)
    : base(name, someInt, anotherInt)
  {
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

The first paragraph of my original answer was all wrong. I have verified that it is possible to mock a (non-static) class type (which must be `public`, and all classes/structs that it is nested inside must be `public` as well, just like for an interface) provided that the instance constructor in question is `public` or `protected` (or `protected internal`). You can then `Setup` all `virtual` (including `abstract`) methods (and properties, indexers etc.) that are `public` or `protected`.

To return to the original question, the problem is simply that named and optional arguments are a kind of syntactic sugar which is not well supported by reflection.

If you're allowed to modify the original `AbstractClassToTest`, another strategy to get around this problem is to overload the instance constructor, that is, add this to your *original* class:

```
protected AbstractClassToTest(string name)
    : this(name, someInt: 10, anotherInt: 20)
{
}
```

In that case you may or may not want to keep the parameters (of the original constructor) optional.

PS! Instance constructors of an `abstract` class should not be `public`. Use `protected` instead.

Comment: Moq can mock abstract classes (and I believe non-abstract classes) just fine. It will create proxies for whatever is abstract or virtual.  You can setup overrides or have it call the base members. I don't know that there is a better way to deal with default parameters in the constructor, however, if @BlueChippy wants to leave the defaults, I wouldn't redefine them like in your example. Instead, leave them out: `internal MockClass(string name) : base(name /* Let the defaults actually default */)`. Point of the story: "Moq won't mock class types, only interfaces" is not true.